# Angular virtual scroll with sticky column and header

Tags: angular, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have a big list of data and I want to display it in a grid, but I don't want to display the whole list as it will be too much stuff on screen and be slow. I want to use a virtual scroll but I want to have the header and the first column to be sticky so if i scroll I can always see them. Right now, I can have one or the other but not both at the same time.

So far I have this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-esodhl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

At first, I was using angular mat-table, but I had the same problem.

Do you have any solution for me?

Comment: https://diprokon.github.io/ng-table-virtual-scroll/#/examples

Comment: That's not good because the only example with a sticky column, the headers does'nt stick. I want both.

Comment: They have both examples separately, you can combine easily